# get gridview column and row from itemtemplate checkbox event

Tags: asp.net, events, gridview, checkbox, itemtemplate

i have gridview with itemTemplate contains a checkbox firing at onCheckChanged.
i want to catch the gridview column and row which the gridview is inside.

how can i do it ?

```
public void PM_chkbx_Chacked_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //What to write here?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have used **datakeys** in gridview and able to get row and particular column.Here gridview id is **grdrequestlist**.

```
public void PM_chkbx_Chacked_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//here you can get row on whcih you checkbox chnged event called

GridViewRow Row = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent);
string requestid = grdrequestlist.DataKeys[Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
string cellvalue=Row.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

This .aspx page design of gridview here you may add your columns in **Columns** section.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdrequestlist" runat="server" DataKeyNames="RequestId" >
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions" >
                 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="PM_chkbx_Chacked" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" oncheckedchanged="PM_chkbx_Chacked_CheckedChanged" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me to get the row number and the datakey. i also need to get the column name in which the CheckBox i checked is located. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I Found the Solution:

```
public void PM_chkbx_Chacked_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = ((GridViewRow)((Control)sender).Parent.Parent);
        int index_row = gvr.RowIndex;
        string role_name = gv_permissions_management.DataKeys[index_row].Value.ToString();
        string fileld_name = ((DataControlFieldCell)((Control)sender).Parent).ContainingField.HeaderText;
        ((DataControlFieldCell)((Control)sender).Parent).BackColor = Color.Red; //Color the Cell

     }
```